# How do I get past the spinning blades of death in Raldbthar?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As part of the quest "[Mourning Never Comes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mourning_Never_Comes)", I'm tasked with dealing with a problem in [Raldbthar](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Raldbthar). Once I completed my objective, I noticed the dungeon continues further along.

I've gotten pretty far, but now I've come to a ramp that goes upwards and has two spinning blades of death on it: if I even so much as graze them, I die instantly.

Now, I know the rest of the dungeon is for a later main quest, "[Discerning the Transmundane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane)". But I was interested to see if I can just press on anyway, like I can do with other quest dungeons. I looked around online and in the official strategy guide, and the very "helpful" advice I've found is "avoid the blades because they'll kill you."

Is that it? Are the blades supposed to be a source of tedium, or is there a trick to getting around them (like, perhaps, a hidden lever to turn them off)? Or are they there to prevent me from continuing further until I have the appropriate quest?

Comment: Any chance you can post a screenshot so we know exactly where you are?

Comment: @Tristan I play on the PS3, so I had to look around for online samples. However, while searching, I [found the solution](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44890/3389) anyway.

Comment: Become Ethereal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking around some more, I found [a playthrough by YouTube user Gullahjack12](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30pSB0EVH6Q#t=12m30s), where he tackles it on the first try:

The trick is to not try to jump over them, but to use the alcoves—that don't look wide enough to fit a person safely—to avoid the blades on the side. By following just behind the blades, you get to a safe zone way before the blade comes back around.

Comment: Yep, on the sides they will go right past you.  Trying to jump over them will only lead to frustration.

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem with being a Khajit, but I had to press into the corner of the alcove and face away from the blades to avoid being hit; the blade's hitbox seems to be quite a bit larger than the mesh would imply.

Answer (score 5):

Slow Time shout works as well.  You can walk between the slow moving blades.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Become Ethereal" Shout. Just the first word is long enough to get you past both of them while running.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space beside them. Wait until they are at the other end, then run against the wall past them. Wait again and do the same thing for the others.